# What do you do when you encounter errors in C that require easy solutions but when you look for the error it doesn't seem to be there?

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors

I just started learning and I'm doing functions in C but I checked and there doesn't seem to be something missing in it. Can you please check what I did wrong, I'm very open to criticism and I would very much appreciate if you could give pointers in how I could avoid and be more aware of these problems, thank you very much.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h>
#define pf printf
#define sf scanf

void fibonacci();
void sum();
void armstrong();

main()
{

int option,input;

pf("OPTIONS:");
pf("1. FIBONACCI");
pf("2. SUM SEQUENCE");
pf("3. ARMSTRONG NUMBER");


pf("\n ENTER OPTION:");
sf(%d, &option);

    if (option== 1)
    {
        pf("FIBONACCI:");
        pf("\n ENTER NUMBER:");
        sf(%d, &input);
        
        fibonacci()
    }

    else if (option== 2)
    {
        pf("SUM SEQUENCE:");
        pf("\n ENTER NUMBER:");
        sf(%d, &input);
        
        sum()
    }

    else if (option== 3)
    {
        pf("ARMSTRONG NUMBER:");
        pf("\n ENTER NUMBER:");
        sf(%d, &input);
        
        armstrong()
    }

    else
    {
        pf("\n OPTION INVALID");
    }

}

void fibonacci()
{
int n1=0,n2=1,n3,x,number;      
    for(i=2;i<number;++i) 
    {    
        n3=n1+n2;    
        printf(" %d",n3);    
        n1=n2;    
        n2=n3;    
    }  
printf("\n OUTPUT: %d %d",n1,n2);
 }    

void sum()
{
int x, y, z=1;
    for (x=1; x<=y; x++)
    {
        z=x*z;
    }
pf("\n FACTORIAL VALUE: %d",z);
}

void armstrong();
{
int input, remainder, actualDigit, sum=0, n;
remainder = input;
    while (remainder != 0) 
    {
       actualDigit= remainder % 10;
       sum= sum + (actualDigit*actualDigit*actualDigit);
       remainder= remainder/10;
    }

    if (sum == input)
        pf("%d is TRUE.", input);
    else
        pf("%d is FALSE.", input);   
}
```

These are the errors I'm encountering.

```
(18) Expression expected in function 'main' 
(8) Expected ')' in    function 'main' 
(9) Inserted ';' in function 'main' 
(18) Expression    expected in function 'main' 
(8) Expected ')' in function 'main' 
(9)    Inserted ';' in function 'main' 
(9) Inserted ';' in function 'main'    
(17) Misplaced else in function 'main' 
(18) Expression expected in    function 'main' 
(8) Expected ')' in function 'main' 
(9) Inserted ';'    in function 'main' 
(9) Inserted ';' in function 'main' 
(17) Misplaced    else in function 'main' 
(18) Expression expected in function 'main'    
(8) Expected ')' in function 'main' 
(9) Inserted ';' in function    'main' 
(9) Inserted ';' in function 'main' 
(17) Misplaced else in    function 'main' 
(272) already defining a function body in function    'main' 
(10) Undefined symbol i in function 'main' 
(272) already    defining a function body in function 'main' 
(23) Lvalue expected in    function 'main' 
(39) Type mismatch in function 'main' 
(8) Expected '}'    in function 'main' 
(8) Expected '}' in function 'main' 
(8) Expected    '}' in function 'main'

Fatal error: Too many errors



Compile done.  Errors: 28,  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, providing the errors (all of them!) as text, not as a screenshot. Additionally tell us what exactly you don't understand about the error messages.

Comment: Just some note: If you use macros like `pf` because you don't want to type `printf` you will get a hard time with programming. The functions from C standard library already have very short names.

Comment: always look at the first error first, the rest of them frequently cascade and snowball from there.

Comment: You have loads of errors and bad practice: 1) `main` has return type `int` and should not have an empty parameter list. 2) Also all your function prototype should provide a parameter list. All statements need a `;` afterwards. 3) This allso applies to calls to your own functions. 4) `scanf` takes a pointer to a string as first argument. `%d` is neither of these. 5) Function prototypes take a `;` at the end, function implementations don't. `void armstrong(); {...` should not have a `;`. 6) `x<=y;` will use uninitialized variable `y` which causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Further to what Gerhardh said (and I have to be careful here, because the last comment I made along these lines got deleted): When I see something like `#define pf printf`, I am likely to stop reading.  That probaby also goes for other readers here, and it probably also goes for your future employers — or, perhaps, your future *non* employers, if you catch my drift.  So, please, reconsider that little shortcut.  Really, truly, it's not nearly as good an idea as it seems at first.

Comment: That was how my teacher taught us about it but thank you I'll remember that.

Comment: I wonder whether some guys become teachers because they don't get another job. And whether there might be some relation between that fact and the stuff they tell their students... ?

Comment: @Gerhardh: An empty parameter list in a function definition defines the function to take no parameters (in contrast, a declaration that is not a definition does not contain information about parameters). The resulting type for the identifier is compatible with `int main(void)` and satisfies C 2018 5.1.2.2.1 1.

Comment: As mentioned, this program is riddled with several errors, violating basic tenets of C syntax. Look at your error list. [The first one is `scanf`](https://godbolt.org/z/PoxfYnPdf). Have you googled `scanf`, found a working example? You need to go through the error list, top to bottom, and make an earnest effort to figure out what the problems are. For many of them, the compiler spells out exactly what is wrong, altho that's not the case for `scanf`. After the errors, give just as much attention to fixing the warnings.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I know that it is valid and means "no paramters", but isn't an empty parameter list for definitions a deprecated feature? Anyway I would consider it bad practice both for definitions and prototypes.

Comment: @Gerhardh: No, it is obsolescent (could be considered for future withdrawal) not deprecated.

Comment: As you're just now learning C, you may have wanted to start with a simpler program before this one.  There are a lot of basic syntax errors here (e.g. where semicolons do and don't belong), and while this is not unusual for a beginner, it's easier to identify and learn from those mistakes if they are in a very short program - e.g. `main` calls a function `foo` which prints Hello World.  That way you don't get overwhelmed by such a huge cascade of error messages caused by many errors compounding each other.